# v-if not updating in vue from radiobuttons toggling value

Tags: vue.js

I'm learning Vue and would appreciate help as I can't find an answer on here or the rest of the internet as to why my radio buttons are not working with a v-if statement even though I have bound the model and I can see the value change.

expected results:

the user toggles if they have a degree using the radio buttons, the div with the class "degree-wrapper" would disappear if they select false.

actual result:

the user toggles if they have a degree using the radio buttons, the div with the class "degree-wrapper" does not disappear if they select false.

what I find odd is that I can see the value change and the value is bound? so why isn't the v-if toggling displaying the "degree-wrapper" div when v-model is changing it to false.

here is my code it's written with classes in vue3 and typescript.

```
<template>
  <div class="page-wrapper">
    <div class="user-data-wrapper">
        <h3>Users Data</h3>
        <p>first name: {{ userData.firstName }}</p>
        <p>last name: {{ userData.secondName }}</p>
        <p>age: {{ userData.age }}</p>
        <p>location: {{ userData.location }}</p>
        <p>date of birth: {{ userData.dateOfBirth }}</p>
        <p>has a degree?: {{ userData.hasDegree }}</p>
    </div>

    <div class="user-update-wrapper">
        <h3>Update your user info</h3>
        <label for="full-name">Fullname: </label><br>
        <input type="text" id="full-name" name="full-name" v-model="fullName"><br>
        <label for="full-name">Do you have a degree?: </label><br>
        <input type="radio" v-model="userData.hasDegree" value="false">false<br>
        <input type="radio" v-model="userData.hasDegree" value="true">true<br>
      <div v-if="userData.hasDegree" class="degree-wrapper">
        <label for="degree-subject">Degree subject: </label><br>
        <select name="degree" id="degree" v-model="userData.degreeSubject">
          <option value="maths">maths</option>
          <option value="computer-science">computer science</option>
          <option value="english">english</option>
          <option value="drama">drama</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="user-output">
      <p>fullname: {{ fullName }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Options, Vue } from 'vue-class-component';
import { Watch } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Options({
  props: {
    msg: String
  }
})
export default class FakeProfile extends Vue {
  msg!: string
  private userData = {
      firstName: 'John',
      secondName: 'Doe',
      age: 31,
      location: 'Essex',
      dateOfBirth: '18/01/1993',
      degreeSubject: '',
      hasDegree: false
  }

  /*
    Example of a getter and setter for computed properties
  */
  get fullName() : string {
    return this.userData.firstName + ' ' + this.userData.secondName;
  }

  /* 
    takes in the newValue for fullName we then split it to update the first and
    last name.
  */
  set fullName(newValue: string) {
    let names = newValue.split(' ')
    this.userData.firstName = names[0]
    this.userData.secondName = names[names.length - 1]
  }
  /* 
  example of a watcher being used to display new selected degree value.
  */

  @Watch('userData.degreeSubject')
  degreeChanged(newVal: string) : void {
    this.userData.degreeSubject = newVal
    alert(`degree subject updated to ${newVal}`)
  }

}
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>

.user-data-wrapper, .user-update-wrapper {
  font-weight: 500;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.page-wrapper {
  margin: auto;
  width: 700px;
}

</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I built a sample component to demonstrate the functionality.  Built with Vue 2 using the Vue CLI, but should be applicable to Vue 3.

```
<template>
  <div class="radio-toggle-show">
    <h4>Radio Toggle Show</h4>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="showDiv" :value="true" v-model="displayDiv">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="showDiv">Show Div</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="hideDiv" :value="false" v-model="displayDiv">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="hideDiv">Hide Div</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" v-if="displayDiv">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h5>Div that is shown or hidden by radio button</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        displayDiv: false
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Ahhh I was missing the bind of the values! thank you for doing this example so I could work it out! much appreciated, unfortunately, I don't have enough points to upvote this but it was a perfect thank you.

Comment: @AdamKinnucane You're welcome.  Let me know if you have any other questions, and since the answer helped, I would appreciate if you would accept the answer.